# How can I create a covariant extension method on a generic interface in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

If the title didn't make sense, here's an example:

```
interface IEat { void Eat; }
class Cat : IEat { void Eat { nom(); } }
class Dog : IEat { void Eat { nom(); nom();nom(); } }
class Labrador : Dog { }
```

I'd like to create an *extension* method like this:

```
public static void FeedAll(this IEnumerable<out IEat> hungryAnimals) {
   foreach(var animal in hungryAnimals) animal.Eat();
}
```

So I can do this:

```
listOfCats.FeedAll();
listOfLabs.FeedAll();
listOfMixedHungryAnimals.FeedAll();
```

Is this possible? Where did I go wrong?

The real-world application here is that "Dog" is a major base class in my application, and there are many subclasses, each of which may have ILists of things from time to time that need to have group operations performed on them. Having to cast them just to call an extension method on a List of an interface they all implement would be suboptimal.

**Edit:**

I goofed up the example a little. My actual code is using `IList`, I was hoping to have Count and index-based operations available. Based on the answers below, I guess I'll have to go another direction for the methods that require IList semantics.

Comment: Does it not just work without the `out` keyword? An `IEnumerable<Dog>` is already an `IEnumerable<IEat>` because of `IEnumerable<T>` being covariant.

Comment: Strilanc, you're right, I edited my question a little. Was hoping to do this with IList, apparently it's not possible (I understand why IList is not covariant, I was just hoping there was a workaround, especially since I don't need Add.)

Comment: Most lists implement `IReadOnlyList<out T>` (unfortunately it can't be put above `IList<T>` though), so that might work.

Comment: It worked perfectly for my use. Moving up to 4.5.1 was something I should've done awhile back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is already covariant, so your extension method can accept an `IEnumerable<IEat>` and an `IEnumerable<Dog>` instance will be a valid argument, making the extension method apply to variables of those types.

Had the definition of the interface not specified that the generic argument was covariant/contravariant then there would be nothing that you extension method could do to allow that argument to be covariant.  If you were using, say, a `List` which is invariant, there is nothing your extension method can do to allow for the use of covariance.

Comment: My actual code uses IList, and I suspected that might be the issue. Edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @richardtallent And `IList` isn't covariant, it's invariant.  As I've said, there is nothing that you can do to make an invariant parameter act covariantly; you simply need to use a covariant type as a parameter.

Comment: This may give me the incentive to move to .NET 4.5, since IList<T> implements IReadOnlyList<T>, which I believe would work around this, no?

Comment: @richardtallent `IReadOnlyList<T>` is a covariant interface, yes.  Of course its existence doesn't make `IList<T>` any more covariant.

Comment: If the interface is not covariant, you don't *need* to do anything to make the argument covariant.  You could make your extension method generic instead: `static void M<T>(this I<T> arg) where T : Dog` would do it.

Answer (score 3):

This will work if you remove the `out`:

```
public static void FeedAll(this IEnumerable<IEat> hungryAnimals) {
   foreach(var animal in hungryAnimals) animal.Eat();
}
```

variance applies to parameters of the the interface itself (`T` in `IEnumerable<T>` in this case) so a `List<Dog>` is compatible with `IEnumerable<IEat>`.

Answer (score 0):

As Servy notes, `Enumerable<T>` is already covariant, but it doesn't need to be.  For older versions where the interface isn't covariant, you could do this:

```
public static void FeedAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> hungryAnimals) where T : IEat
{
    foreach(var animal in hungryAnimals) animal.Eat();
}
```

Comment: @hangar What do you mean?  Overload resolution will handle overloads with constructed generic types, too.  You might not call the overload you think you're calling, however; is that it?

Comment: No, C# does not overload by generic constraints. See [Eric Lippert's explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/).

Comment: @hangar sure, but I'm not talking about that.  I'm talking about constructed generic types such as `this IEnumerable<Carnivore>`.

Comment: I guess that original comment sounded a bit harsh. If you don't need to overload with different constraints, then this does indeed work.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need the out it gets passed by reference so it will work with out it.

Comment: The parameter does not get passed by reference, so that is not why it works.

Comment: Read the link in the section that says Passing by reference vs passing by value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Comment: What about that article are you referring to?  I know what the difference is.  If you think that this method is passing the parameter by reference then *you* need to read that again, because that's not happening here at all.  Since there is no use of `out` or `ref` the parameter is passed by value.

Comment: His mistake was using the keyword out in the signature. The reason he did that was because he believed he had a need for it. Basically this line is what i meant. "Now, if you pass an object that is based on this type to a method, a reference to the object is passed. The following example passes an object of type SampleRefType to method ModifyObject"

Comment: The way that he used the keyword `out` is simply invalid syntax and would result in a compile time error.  It is not in a valid location to indicate that the parameter is passed by reference.  On top of that, the implicit parameter to an extension method cannot be passed by reference; it is not valid to do so.  Additionally, it's quite clear from looking at the question that he's not trying to indicate that the parameter should be passed by reference, he's saying that it needs to be covariant.  Finally, if it were passed by reference, which it's not, that wouldn't cause it to be covariant.